# How t to set default host on rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get render string on rake task. But url something like `new_book_url` doesn't have host..

```
# on rake
controller = ApplicationController.new.tap do |controller|
  controller.request  = ActionDispatch::Request.new({})
end
p controller.render_to_string('books/index', layout: nil) #=> "<a href=\"http://:/books/new\">New Book URL</a>\n"
p Rails.application.config.action_mailer[:default_url_options] #=> {:host=>"localhost", :port=>3000}
p Rails.application.routes.default_url_options #=> {}

# books/index
<%= link_to 'New Book URL', new_book_url %>
```

When I set `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer[:default_url_options]`, it doesn't work...

Comment: Try setting `Rails.application.config.domain`.

Comment: Where? And does is work?
NoMethodError: undefined method `domain' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fa7cdc344d0>

Comment: That is strange. What's your Rails version?

Comment: It doesn't work on console too. Rails version is 4.2.3.

Comment: Check an answer, I nailed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `default_url_options` as your controller's instance method:

```
controller = ApplicationController.new.tap do |controller|
  controller.request  = ActionDispatch::Request.new({})
  def controller.default_url_options
    host = {'production' => 'production.example.org', 'development' => 'development.example.org'}[Rails.env]
    {host: host}
  end
end
p controller.render_to_string('books/index', layout: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I set `default_url_options` on controller and then works!

Comment: You are welcome. It's still strange that `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options` doesn't work.